# how to verify asymptotic upper bound ( substitution method) $T(n)= 4T(n/2 +2)+n$

Tags: substitution

i guess $O(n^2)$ and
$T(n)= 4C(n/2+2)^2 - C(n/2+2) +n$ 
      ...(??)
    $\leq C(n^2)$

is this right? and how can i verify this problem using the substitution method...
help me

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE... Next time, please learn to use formatting